# Sequelize - Is there a way to automatically generate models and their associations from an existing database?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Is there a way to generate models and associations (through automation) based on an existing database?

For example, take customers and orders:

```
Customer
---------
id, name

Order
---------
id, customerId, orderDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **[Sequelize-Auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-auto)** for this

> Automatically generate models for SequelizeJS via the command line.

Command for that :

```
[node] sequelize-auto -h <host> -d <database> -u <user> -x [password] -p [port]  --dialect [dialect] -c [/path/to/config] -o [/path/to/models] -t [tableName] -C
```

**[TUTORIAL LINK](https://medium.com/@saikrishna.d/get-create-database-models-for-existing-database-tables-with-nodejs-python-51dc0856abd7)**

Comment: I've used this but it does not pick up the associations unless I'm not doing something right.

Comment: Try https://github.com/gbahamondezc/sequelize-models.  It says it generates associations but right now it will not run for me.  See https://github.com/gbahamondezc/sequelize-models/issues/10